# Spring Boot application using up memory and crashing on Openshift 3.1, but not on plain Docker

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, spring-cloud, openshift-origin, spring-cloud-config

I have a simple Spring Boot Application, a Spring Cloud Config Server that is going to be run on Openshift 3.1. The problem is that when running on this platform, the application increases its size steadily until it uses up the set up  container max memory (512MB), crashing eventually, and making Openshift restart it.

We configure this application on Openshift with a Dockerfile. Deploying it directly on a simple Docker container the application behaves normally. I load-tested it with JMeter and its memory compsumption stays at 256MB, no matter the load.

Could this be an Openshift bug? Is there any solution for this?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM java:8
RUN curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -f "http://${APPLICATION-URL}" -o ./app.jar 
EXPOSE 8888  
ENTRYPOINT java -jar ./app.jar
```

Comment: Are there any relevant errors in the Java logs?  With GC logging turned on do you see anything unusual?  OpenShift by default runs your container as non-root, but that usually manifests as crashes at startup (because of a permission denied error).  You can run as root by adding `oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default`

Comment: The Java logs just show "Killed" when the pod uses up the memory, forcing a restart.

Comment: Did you try setting memory limits on pod?

Comment: did you get the solution?? I have the same issue as you :(